# Largest substring composed of identical characters

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to develop method that will return the length of largest substring composed of identical characters form string that is passed as argument, but without using any of `.NET libraries`.

For example if we pass `aaacccccdefffgg` as parameter the biggest substring is `ccccc` and method should return 5.

Here is my working solution :

```
public static int GetMaxSubstringLenght(char[] myArray)
    {
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if (myArray.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int j = i + 1;
                int currentMax = 1; // string has some value, so we start with 1
                while (myArray[i] == myArray[j])
                {
                    currentMax++;
                    if (max < currentMax)
                    {
                        max = currentMax;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }                
        }
        return max;
    }
```

The code above will return expected result, but there will be some unnecessary iteration in `for loop` that I want to avoid. In first iteration when `i=0`it will compare it until `j=2` and then will get out of `while loop` and start second iteration in `for loop` comparing the one at `[1]` index with `[2]`, which we already did in previous iteration.So basically, when first iteration is completed, next one should start from the last value of `j`. How can I achieve that ?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: If the code is working and you want to improve it, then it's a good question for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach:

```
public static int MaxSubstringLength(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return 0;

    int max = 0, cur = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; ++i, ++cur)
    {
        if (s[i] != s[i-1])
        {
            max = cur > max ? cur : max;
            cur = 0;
        }
    }

    return cur > max ? cur : max;
}
```

[EDIT] Simplified the code.
[EDIT2] Simplified the code further.

Comment: Sorry, but `MaxSubstringLength2("abb")` returns `1` when `2` is expected

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yeah, I already noticed that, and it's fixed.

Comment: Empty string (`""`) returns `1` when `0` is expected; `null` string throws exception (method is `public` so `null` is one of possible inputs)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Added a check for null, but I think in real code I'd probably not allow this to be called with null, but instead would have `Contract.Requires(s != null);`

Comment: +1; Final suggestion: if you've tested for `string.IsNullOrEmpty` you have no need in `cur = s.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 6):

Since you want "Largest substring..." let's take `String` as argument and return `String`

```
public static String GetMaxSubstring(String value) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return "";

  int bestCount = 0;
  char bestChar = '\0';

  int currentCount = 0;
  char current = '\0';

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    if ((i == 0) || (value[i] != current))
      currentCount = 0;

    currentCount += 1;
    current = value[i];

    if (currentCount > bestCount) {
      bestCount = currentCount;
      bestChar = current;
    }
  }

  return new String(bestChar, bestCount);
}
```

....

```
// "ccccc"
String result = GetMaxSubstring("aaacccccdefffgg");
// 5
int length = result.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

you also can do it with one loop:

```
public static int GetMaxSubstringLenght(char[] myArray)
{
    int max = 0;
    char currentchar = myArray[0];
    int count = 1;

    for each(char c in myArray)
    {
        if(currentchar != c)
        {
            count = 1;
            currentchar = c;
        }

        if(count > max)
        {
            max = count;
        } 
        count++;
    }

    return max;
}
```

I changed the code... now this code does not use math.max and I think I eleminated the mistake... I've no IDE at the moment to test it

Comment: Test failed: `GetMaxSubstringLenght(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'b'})` returns `1` when `2` is expected

Comment: I've also mentioned that I should do it without help of any library, including Math.

Answer (score 1):

```
    static int LongestCharSequence(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return 0;
        var prevChar = '\0';
        int cmax = 0;
        int max = 1;
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (c != prevChar)
            {
                cmax = 1;
                prevChar = c;
            }
            else
            {
                if (++cmax > max) max = cmax;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: That's going to return 0 for the string "abcdefg".

Comment: @Jim Mischel, clumsy return statement added

Comment: If you checked for the string being null or empty at the start, then you could initialize `max` to 1, and you wouldn't need that screwy `return` statement.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, yeah this way it looks cleaner

Comment: I was thinking `if string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) return 0;` Then initialize `max` to 1, and you don't need the null coalescing operator in the `foreach`.

Comment: A small price to pay for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int GetMaxSubstringLenght(char[] myArray)
{
    if (myArray.Length == 0)
        return 0;

    if (myArray.Length == 1)
        return 1;

    int max = 1;
    int localMax = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length - max; i++ )
    {

        if (myArray[i] == myArray[i + 1])
        {
            localMax++;
        }
        else
        {
            max = Math.Max(max, localMax);
            localMax = 1;
        }
    }
    return Math.Max(max, localMax);           
}
```

Comment: ...And when `myArray == null` you'll have an exception thrown

Answer (score 1):

recursion!

```
    static int LongestCharSequence(string s)
    {
        int i = (s?.Length ?? 0) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        for (; i < s?.Length; i++)
            if (s[i] != s[i - 1]) return Math.Max(i, LongestCharSequence(s.Substring(i)));
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using my favorite nested loop technique:

```
public static int MaxSubstringLength(string s)
{
    int maxLength = 0;
    for (int length = s != null ? s.Length : 0, pos = 0; pos < length;)
    {
        int start = pos;
        while (++pos < length && s[pos] == s[start]) { }
        maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, pos - start);
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```